# why does redirect for file download fire angular ui-router otherwise rule?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My routing scheme has an otherwise rule:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/a");
```

I have this function:

```
function getCSV(TableName) {
            window.location = API_ENDPOINT + '/EditValidationXREF/GetCSV?TableName=' + TableName;
        }
```

The issue is that when I fire the function `getCSV`, i may be at state z but I automatically get rerouted to a (which I assume is the otherwise rule in action). Why does this happen and how can I avoid this (i.e. stay at state z after the download).

Comment: @KevinB What do you mean by that? The file is downloading just fine. After the download though I get rerouted back to state a....

Comment: oh... well that sounds like the default browser behavior. when you redirect to a download, it'l download and not actually leave the page.

Comment: The routing issue though, i'm not sure of. It should send you back to the same state, assuming each state is properly being added to history.

Comment: but it isn't going back, I mean, It is going back to the correct page but it is not going back to the page#route. I guess that is why the router is redirecting me to the otherwise rule. How can I get the browser to go back to the same url it was it prior to download?

Comment: You could avoid the issue entirely if you used an iframe to initiate the download instead

Comment: @KevinB Do you mean that I add an Iframe with display=none on it and then redirect its location? Would that be $window.getElementById('iframeId').location ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. The link that was executing `getCSV` looked like:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.getCSV('TableName')">Interchanges</a>
```

which obviously redirected the browser to the page without the route (and so triggered the otherwise rule as intended).

Solution:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="vm.getCSV('TableName')">Interchanges</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
function getCSV(TableName) {
            window.location = API_ENDPOINT + '/EditValidationXREF/GetCSV?TableName=' + TableName;
        }
```

is actually changing the location of the window to something, something that the application is unable to identify to, or resolve. Thats the reason, its navigating to the URL associated to otherwise. One of the alternative methods to simply download the file is to change the above function to:

```
function getCSV(TableName) {
            window.open(API_ENDPOINT + '/EditValidationXREF/GetCSV?TableName=' + TableName, _blank);
        }
```

This would download the file, without the navigation.